# Do "mandates" conditions in the C++ standard always result in an error?

Tags: c++, standards, c++20, std

The draft C++ standard lists some requirements on library functions using the phrase "mandates". For example, [[util.smartptr.shared.cast]](http://eel.is/c++draft/util.smartptr.shared.cast#lib:%F0%9D%9A%9C%F0%9D%9A%91%F0%9D%9A%8A%F0%9D%9A%9B%F0%9D%9A%8E%F0%9D%9A%8D_%F0%9D%9A%99%F0%9D%9A%9D%F0%9D%9A%9B,%F0%9D%9A%9C%F0%9D%9A%9D%F0%9D%9A%8A%F0%9D%9A%9D%F0%9D%9A%92%F0%9D%9A%8C_%F0%9D%9A%99%F0%9D%9A%98%F0%9D%9A%92%F0%9D%9A%97%F0%9D%9A%9D%F0%9D%9A%8E%F0%9D%9A%9B_%F0%9D%9A%8C%F0%9D%9A%8A%F0%9D%9A%9C%F0%9D%9A%9D) says this about `std::static_pointer_cast`:

> `template<class T, class U>`
> `shared_ptr<T> static_pointer_cast(const shared_ptr<U>& r) noexcept;`
>
> [...]
>
> Mandates: The expression `static_­cast<T*>((U*)nullptr)` is well-formed.

Is the compiler required to give an error if this condition isn't met (for example if `T` is `char` and `U` is `int`), or is it just undefined behavior? [structure.sepcifications] [defines](http://eel.is/c++draft/structure.specifications#3.2) "mandates" conditions as rendering the program [ill-formed](http://eel.is/c++draft/defns.ill.formed#:program,ill-formed) if not met, but it's not clear to me if that must result in an error.

Comment: Yes, "ill-formed" means the compiler must diagnose it. If it's not required to be diagnosed then it's usually "ill formed no diagnostic required".

Comment: @cigien - That's not true.   Ill-formed (on its own) does not mean that a diagnostic is required.   For example, a well-formed program is required to satisfy the one-definition rule, but not meeting the one-definition rule (which would mean the program is ill-formed) does not require a diagnostic.

Comment: @Peter Yes, and as far as I'm aware, violating ODR is explicitly IFNDR, not just IF. See the dupe, it's one of the example there.

Comment: The *mandate* in the provided example is designated as **well-formed**.